# Regular expression to check for string between special characters in java

Tags: java, regex

I have to check if the string provided has a specific format. The format is as follows: "This is just an `#<example string>` just for test. This string has to be of this `#<specific format>`".

If you look at the string, it has special characters `#<>` with some string in between `#<` and `>`. I tried with regular expression: `Pattern.compile("^[#<a-zA-Z0-9>]*$").matcher(string).find()` but it returns true even if I don't provide the special characters at the beginning or at the end.

I tried with an if condition too: `if(string.matcher("#<"))` but I think this approach is lame. I'd rather go with the regular expresson.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: It could be like this if there can not be spaces between the brackets `^#<[a-zA-Z0-9]+>$`

Comment: @Thefourthbird, I tried this but it returns false

Comment: Try `^#<[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+>$` with the space added to the character class or try `^#<[^<>]*>$` to match any char except `<>` between the brackets.

Comment: @localhost, can u provide a concerte example, is it a valid string "#<abol$%3#tabol>"? and is it "abol#<xxx%$3yyytabol>" also a valid string?

Comment: yes, "#<abol$%3#tabol>" would be a valid string

Comment: and also, "abol#<xxx%$3yyytabol>" a valid string? and if not why..pls clarify

Comment: "abol#<xxx%$3yyytabol>" is not a valid string because there is no space between "abo" and "#<xxx%$3yyytabol>". The pattern is #<something like> this. it just occurs in the sentence encapsulating one or more word(s)

Comment: Like this? `(?<!\S)#<[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?: [a-zA-Z0-9]+)>(?!\S)` https://regex101.com/r/VY1k38/1

Comment: This works perfectly, so does @Matthew's solution. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match 1 or more "words" using the chars `a-zA-Z0-9` between `#<...>` and a whitespace boundary on the left and right,  you could use

```
(?<!\S)#<[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?: [a-zA-Z0-9]+)*>(?!\S)
```

In Java

```
String regex = "(?<!\\S)#<[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?: [a-zA-Z0-9]+)*>(?!\\S)";
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pdxXsS/1)

Answer (score 1):

Try: `Pattern.compile("#<(.*?)>")`

Suggest you use a website like https://regex101.com/ to help you build these.